# Analogy between Mac Lane's coherence theorem and independence of bracketing

Tags: monoidal-categories

It is an elementary fact that if a binary operation on a set is associative then any multi-term product can be written unambiguously without bracketing.  Superficially the coherence theorem for monoidal categories seems like a higher order version of this statement.  Is this a good analogy, and can it be formalised?

Comment: It's absolutely a good analogy, and it's part of a ladder of structures (monoid, monoidal category, monoidal bicategory, ...) in which the equations at one level are promoted to isomorphisms at the next which then obey their own coherence laws. You might enjoy reading the papers by Baez and Dolan including Higher-Dimensional Algebra 0, and Categorification (in the series Contemporary Mathematics; it's Higher Category Theory: Workshop in Higher Category Theory and Physics ed. by Getzler and Kapranov).

Comment: The most obvious higher-order associativity around is the interchange law. This can be interpreted as saying that a certain diagram built from four parts is unambiguous.